# PHP date() doesn't work?

Tags: php, date, time

I am trying to add 1 minute to the current time:

```
echo date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime("+60 seconds"));
echo '<br />';
echo date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
```

The output is in both cases:

```
2012-09-02 17:09:02
2012-09-02 17:09:02
```

Which is obviously wrong (in both cases - the current time is in my country 1AM).

What I am doing wrong? I have saved into the datetime column the value `2012-09-02 17:09:38` and now I try to add to the current time 60 seconds and then if the difference between stored datetime and the current datetime is less than 60s, then I want to inset another row in the database...

But the problem is, the `date()` function displays weird output.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

not

```
("Y-m-d H:m:s");
```

m is month, it can't be minutes as well

Answer (score 3):

`date("m")` will show the current *month* numerically. So this is why your +60 seconds does not work. Use `date("Y-m-d H:i:s")`

Why the current time is wrong could be several reasons. Probably something with time or timezone settings on your server.

Answer (score 1):

As far as timezone goes, this might help you: [date_default_timezone_set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php)